# Optimise a sql query with a loop

Tags: sql, loops

Lets say i have a table with one column for every month. Is it possible to Loop thruu this 12 columns somehow so i don't have to write 12 different select Statements?

Instead of

```
SELECT a.ArtikelName,a.Number, 
jan = (SELECT b.Month1 FROM Budget b LEFT OUTER JOIN on b.number = a.number),
feb = (SELECT b.Month2 FROM Budget b LEFT OUTER JOIN on b.number = a.number),
mar = (SELECT b.Month3 FROM Budget b LEFT OUTER JOIN on b.number = a.number),
apr = (SELECT b.Month4 FROM Budget b LEFT OUTER JOIN on b.number = a.number),
may = (SELECT b.Month5 FROM Budget b LEFT OUTER JOIN on b.number = a.number),   
FROM Artikel a
```

Can i somehow make a Loop here and go thruu the different months? Because except of the monthnumber it's exactly desame question.

Comment: You should stop using correlated subqueries, they are essentially condeming your query to row by row performance. They are a technique of last resort. Almost all of them can easily be replaced with joins. You should also stop thinking of looping through records, this is a bad thing in database terms, you work on data sets not loop through records.

Answer (score 2):

Join `Budget` once to `Artikel`.

```
SELECT a.ArtikelName,a.Number, 
jan = b.Month1,
feb = b.Month2,
FROM Artikel a
LEFT OUTER JOIN Budget b on b.number = a.number
```

Btw, I have never seen the strange `LEFT JOIN` syntax of yours. I don't even quite understand what it means. It is probably better to use the standard `JOIN` syntax that everybody knows and understands.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
SELECT a.ArtikelName,a.Number, 
b.Month1 as Jan,
b.Month2 as Feb
... etc. 
FROM Artikel a
LEFT OUTER JOIN Budget b on b.number = a.number
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOINS`

```
SELECT a.artikelname, 
       a.number, 
       jan = b.month1, 
       feb = b.month2, 
       mar = b.month3, 
       apr = b.month4, 
       may = b.month5 
FROM   artikel a 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN budget b 
                    ON b.number = a.number
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is SQL Transact/SQL Server you can use a EXEC sp_columns ''
it will return all data of the specified table with its column names and datatype
Check this link -> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259626(v=sql.80).aspx

You can then put it into a CURSOR, for processing each column, Check This link for cursor -> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is a method to loop through database tables and columns but it is not a shortcut for this case because it takes much more code than 12 lines. To have it around, here is the link of an example: http://dushi.co.uk/2009/07/15/loop-through-database-tables-and-columns/

Basicly, it calculates how many columns there are and generates a select query for each.

Answer (score 0):

Well sorry for my bad example my query is way more complicated than my example.

I post it my orginal query. Instead of copying so much code on each month i want to know if i make a Loop there.. To Keep the query short i only Show example with first 2 months

```
SELECT d.Keyword1,
Jan = ((SELECT CONVERT(INTEGER, Sum(Isnull(a.PlanAbsatz_Mt1,0)))
FROM dbo.JSBudgetDetail a
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.JSBudgetHeader b ON b.ID = a.HeaderID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Art c ON a.Artikel = c.number
            WHERE b.VersionNotActive = 0 and b.Markt=2800 and c.ArtMisC2No=10 and c.ArtMisC5No=2014 and c.ArtMisC1No = 1011 and b.VerkRegion = 'default' and c.ArtMisC3No = 4160 and c.Number=d.Number)) ,
Feb = ((SELECT CONVERT(INTEGER, Sum(Isnull(a.PlanAbsatz_Mt2,0)))
FROM dbo.JSBudgetDetail a
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.JSBudgetHeader b ON b.ID = a.HeaderID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Art c ON a.Artikel = c.number
            WHERE b.VersionNotActive = 0 and b.Markt=2800 and c.ArtMisC2No=10 and c.ArtMisC5No=2014 and c.ArtMisC1No = 1011 and b.VerkRegion = 'default' and c.ArtMisC3No = 4160 and c.Number=d.Number)) 
From Art d
LEFT OUTER JOIN JSBudgetDetail e ON e.Artikel = d.Number
LEFT OUTER JOIN JSBudgetHeader f ON f.ID = e.HeaderID
WHERE f.VersionNotActive = 0 and d.ArtMisC2No = 10 and d.ArtMisC5No = 2014 and f.Markt = 2800 and d.ArtMisC1No = 1011 and d.ArtMisC3No = 4160 and f.VerkRegion = 'default'
GROUP BY d.Keyword1, d.Number
ORDER BY d.Keyword1
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a SQL Server 2005+ database, we can take a slightly different approach and use `PIVOT / UNPIVOT`. This should provide extra readability, as well as flexibility going forward.

[Here is the link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28SQL.105%29.aspx) to the detailed MSDN article, with examples. In this case, `UNPIVOT` would be the solution.